# Realtek audio, Logitec subwoofer silent

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, logitech-speakers

I have an Asus Windows 10 PC with onboard Realtek audio (driver version 6.0.1.7687). I recently purchased [Logitech Z313 speakers](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/speaker-system-z313). I have good audio from the 2 satellites, but the subwoofer is dead silent. If I put my hand on it, I feel very week vibrations, but even if I crank the volume I can hear no bass. When I googled the problem, I saw mention somewhere that my audio codec might not support a subwoofer. I'm not sure I believe that, but if it's true I'll just buy a different sound card.

Do you think my onboard Realtek should send bass to my subwoofer? I have tried twiddling every relevant setting in the "Realtek HD Audio Manager" program, but nothing I do produces sound from the subwoofer.

The speakers connect to the PC via 1 cable. So the sattelites plug into the subwoofer, and then it plugs into the PC. Here are my realtek settings (again, I have tried changing just about everything here, but still couldn't get bass from the sub):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLdoG.jpg

Comment: This is really a 2 channel system, if your not getting bass out of the sub, it's either connected wrong or the speaker is bad.

Comment: easy enough to verify the speaker is functional. Have you opened your Realtek HD Audio Manager and verified the configuration is correct?

Comment: @ruggb, did you read the last sentence of my question? ;) To answer your question, yes, I tried that. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @acejavelin, I just tried plugging these Logetech speakers into my smartphone and I get decent thumping base from the subwoofer. When I plug them back into my PC (and play the same song), I get no bass. I did notice that if I put my hand on the subwoofer, I can feel weak vibrations...but no bass is heard or felt.

Comment: @Psycogeek, I added the info you requested at the end of my question (last paragraph). As far as your "full range speakers" comment, I have tried turning that on and off, but I get the same result from both (no bass).

Comment: 1 cable with how many connections? of what type optical digital or analog?  Take your average 3.5mm jack if it has 3 seperated connection points on it, then it is connecting 2 possible signals up.  If I am thinking what acejavelin is thinking , then you only ever set this up as "stereo"  and certannly not as a 2.1 5.1 type of system. you do not select the presence of a subwoofer, because it is not seperately connected.  One of the speaker setups i have here uses that method and classed itself as a 2.1 , but the only .1 part is seperated out at the subwoofer amp, not back in software.

Comment: @Psycogeek, it is one cable with one 3.5mm connector. As I mentioned in my question, I have tried all of the available speaker configurations in Realtek HD Audio Manager, including Stereo, with no bass output from setting change I have attempted. I just tried Stereo again, same result...no bass.

Comment: My question is if it is possible to get bass from my Realtek chipset. I am willing to by a new soundcard if necessary. I have searched everywhere to identify my Realtek codec, but I can't find it. Device Manager, the System Info windows app, the Belarc Advisor utility, they all say "Realtek High Definition Audio". :\

Comment: i dont know (what you have occuring isnt normal at all). Microsoft (updates) will even driver most of the realtek chips, so you could potentially uninstall the whole realtek software/driver package and have a limited driver (from updates) that works with microsoft sound property pages only.   In seperate connected sub systems often there is a seperate sub volume on the remote or on the sub/amp. I cant think how drivers would change unless not configured corrrect.